# Rails 4 checkbox not working, no changes in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a big problem with checkboxes and boolean values. I want to simply change value of one field in db using checkbox. Code is like this:

Collection_controller:

```
def update
@collection = Collection.find(params[:id]).album
if @collection.update_attributes(:for_sale)
  flash[:success] = "success"
  redirect_to current_user
else
  flash[:success] = "not working"
end
end

def collection_params
  params.require(:collection).permit(:to_buy, :for_sale)
end
```

and form:

```
<%= form_for collection do |f| %>
<div><%= f.check_box :for_sale%></div>
<%= f.submit "sale", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Is there anyone who know why it is not working?

EDIT

One important fact, after clicking 'submit' I have flash message 'success'. So why I dont see the changes? It is problem in controller, or somewhere else?

Comment: Try `form_for @collection`.

Comment: form is rendered for @collection, so here should be collection. Anyway I checked your solution and is not working

Comment: Please see the examples at `http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for`.  A symbol will  work and an instance (`@`) variable will work, but I don't think a bare variable will work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this should be hash of parameters.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in what you want to update.  Possibly like so:

```
if @collection.update_attributes(collection_params)
```

But it looks like you're incorrectly setting your collection variable to be the album of the collection, so fix that too

```
@collection = Collection.find(params[:id]).album
```

should be

```
@collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
```